# Select the same feature multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, openlayers-3

My aim is that when I click the icon (the feature)

- One time: Center and info window
- Second time: Zoom to 9
- Third time: Zoom to 17 and switch to satellite view.

I am using the Select interaction focusing onto the feature and opening an info window:

```
/*      Click Popover       */
selectClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
    condition: ol.events.condition.click,
    multi: false,
    layers: [vectorLayer, potentialsLayer]
});
map.addInteraction(selectClick);

selectClick.on('select', (event) => {
    if (e.selected.length !== 0) {
        const feature = event.selected[0];
        const site = feature.get("site");

        if (feature.get('layer') == "main")
            popover.open(site, true);

    } else
        popover.close();        
});
```

Popover is a class instance for handling focus, zoom, and info window.  In it, this cycle zoom is already worked out, but if the feature is already selected and the user clicks the icon the select interaction will not trigger (as nothing is selecting or deselecting)

I realize I could go back to `map.on('click'...)`, but I think the select interaction is cleaner.

Is there anyway to implement this within the Select interaction?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this way. You have 3 steps process for each feature.

1. Select the feature. Keep track of this feature  and step number(ie 1.Center and info window) for that feature. The selected feature can be obtained from selected event.For tracking of a feature, you can assign id or name to the feature when they are added in vector layers.
2. Do the details of functionalitis of step 1.Center and info window.
3. Then `select.getFeatures().clear();` which clears the selected feature collections and allows you to re-select the same feature again.
4. When the same feature is selected again, perform step no 2.
5. Repeat the same stuffs for step 3.

Comment: I thought the same but the issue then becomes deselecting: as there is no feature selected, when you press elsewhere from that feature it will not trigger to deselect it (i.e. close the info window).